# Restore original page when navigating back after history.pushState

Tags: javascript, browser-history

I'm using `history.pushState` to create a 'fake' results page after the user submits a form. However, when I navigate back, the visible page stays the same. What is an easy way to get the original page - unmodified by javascript, but with the form filled out - after pressing back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to watch the current address for changes and react to it yourself.

See this example:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onpopstate

Also have a look at the documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history/

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle the `onpopstate` event and reload the previous page manually:

```
window.onpopstate = function() {
    location.reload();
};
```